# How to run an entire R script at once

Tags: r, rstudio

How do I run an entire R code script in RStudio?

When I click on the Run button in RStudio, the code runs only on a line-by-line basis and I want it to execute all the code at once instead of running through line by line.

So far the only method I've tried that works is selecting the entire script and then clicking the run button. The other option is running line by line.

Is there an easier way to run the entire script with a single button or a shortcut?

Comment: Also is there a way to stop a script as its running in R studio? Or a shortcut? Sometimes it gives me a + sign thinking I have more code to give it but I actually want the code to stop.

Comment: My guess is that you're using RStudio because of your previous question.  But this is completely editor specific.  You'll need to provide more details and even then the question isn't really appropriate for SO.  So before it gets closed... check the menu called "Code" - it will give you the keyboard shortcuts for various options (assuming you're using RStudio).

Comment: Hey Dason, thank you for your response, but even in regular R I still have a problem running the entire script

Comment: Don't forget that http://stats.stackexchange.com/ can be a useful resource as well for questions regarding R.

Comment: In RGui just highlight the region you want to run and then use Ctrl-r  (assuming you're using windows)

Comment: What about using `source()`. Also, if R keeps prompting you for more input, you probably have mismatched parentheses or brackets somewhere.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming your script is named "myScript.r", you can use something like `source("myScript.r", echo = TRUE)` to run the entire script.

Comment: How about a rmd document?

Comment: Genius, I was going crazy in VSCode selecting all and then running. Problem was it would crash most times that way, I had to start running line by line to work. Maybe it executes all the code at once when selected and causes order of operation errors, i.e lines running out of turn. Anyway now I can just cmd+ent on this one line!!!!!!

Answer (score 53):

Or take a look at `Rscript` for running R scripts from the command line. In addition, in Rstudio you can run the entire script by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> without selecting any code. In addition, there is a shortcut to `source` the current script file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>), which runs the script without echoing each line.

Comment: How do you install Rscript? my windows computer doesn't recognise it as a program name although I have R installed